# Declaring a method when creating an object

Tags: java, object, methods, anonymous-class, anonymous-inner-class

Why first way is correct, but second isn't?

---

First way:

```
new Object() {
    public void a() {
        /*code*/
    }
}.a();
```

---

Second way:

```
Object object = new Object() {
    public void a() {
        /*code*/
    }
};

object.a();
```

---

And where can I find more information about it?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[`java.lang.Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html) has no `a` methods declared (2), while the anonymous class returned by [the class instance creation expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9) `new Object() { public void a() {} }` does (1).

Use Java 10's [local variable type inference](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286) (`var`) to make the second option as valid as the first one.

```
var object = new Object() {
    public void a() {}
};
object.a();
```

Comment: Note that `var` was introduced in Java 10 and will not be available in lower versions.

Comment: @ernest_k It's really not that hard or interesting. By saying `Object object = ` you are downcasting to an `Object`, `var` gives `object` its actual correct type that has `a()` defined.

Comment: @SombreroChicken I understand the effect of `var` here. But beside the first syntax in the question, there was no other way (that I know) to have a static reference to the anonymous type. Now I know that `var` can be used for that. Even more, it allows one to make multiple method calls from the anonymous class. I find that strangely new and interesting!

Comment: You can also declare an interface that has the `a()` method and create an anonymous object from *that* instead of `Object`, which would work in lower versions that don't support `var`. E.g., `private interface HasA { public void a(); }` then `HasA object = new HasA() { public void a() { ... } };`.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Yes, but then the implementation is not inlined. I presumed that they were inlining it for a reason. Different options for different usages, of course.

Comment: @ernest_k there is, since Java 8. E.g. `Optional.of(new Object() { 
 public void a() {  /*code*/  }  }) .ifPresent(object -> object.a());` It’s all about defining variables without having to name the type, see also [Implied anonymous types inside lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43987285/2711488).

Comment: @Holger Thanks! Now that you mention that, I can even think of `(new Object() {public void b() {System.out.println("bbbb");}}).b();` :-) - usable in even older versions, I suppose.

Comment: @ernest_k yes, that was possible in earlier versions too, but I assumed you were aware of it when you wrote your comment, as you mentioned that the new syntax “*allows one to make multiple method calls from the anonymous class*”, which is the fundamental difference between calling a method directly on the creation expression and using a lambda expression or `var` declaration for it.

Comment: @Holger Fair enough. But before this answer, none of this had never occurred to me (one method or many, I'd just never seen this trick)... And your `Optional`-based approach is nifty. I'm thinking of using it in the next code I submit for peer review :-).

Answer (score 22):

In the second option, you assign your new object to a reference of type `Object`. Because of this, only methods defined in `java.lang.Object` could be called on that reference.

And in the first option, you basically create new object of anonymous class that extends `java.lang.Object`. That anonymous class has the additional method `a()`, which is why you can call it.

Answer (score 2):

Java is statically typed. When you say `object.a()` it is looking for the method `a` in the `Object` class which is not present. Hence it does not compile.

What you can do is get the method of `object` using reflection as shown below :

```
Object object = new Object() {
  public void a() {
     System.out.println("In a");
  }
}

Method method = object.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("a");
method.invoke(object, null);
```

This would print

> In a

Comment: That's not true. Java uses static typing (you can see it in your example - `Object object` - you just declared its type!). It uses polymorphism to determine which method should be called, but that's a different thing than dynamic typing. Some debate about dynamic vs static can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517582/what-is-the-difference-between-statically-typed-and-dynamically-typed-languages)

Comment: you should have pointed out that calling the method through reflection is the last thing OP wants :)

Comment: @MatthewRock The JVM does support dynamic dispatch, however.

Comment: @SolomonUcko JVM is not Java. Dynamic dispatch is also not something that makes a language a static one. C++ has dynamic dispatch for virtual methods, but is still a static language.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, you will have to do a bit of correction
Both are ways to access the private member of a class. By using first way you don' have to pre-declare the method.ex: -

```
public class demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Object() {
        public void a() {
            /*code*/
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    }.a();

}

}
```

But by using second way you will have to explicitly declare the method a(); either in abstract class or in interface then you can override it. like: -

```
interface Object
{
public void a();
}
class demo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object object = new Object() {
        public void a() {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }

    }; object.a();


}

}
```

I hope it will help a bit.

Comment: *"to access the private member of a class"* what's the private member?